# Задача обедающих философов Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, deadlock

При реализации обедающих философов на джаве возникла такая проблема, у меня есть философов и я не понимаю как сделать так, чтоб они брали вилки вместе и не вылезали при этом ошибки, на данном этапе код работает правильно, но они берут всё такие вилки по очереди, будто задача consumer и  producer, но мне нужно именно, динамическое выполнение данного действия, тоесть чтоб свободные вилки могли брать одновременно, а не по очереди, думаю тут проблема в lock-ере, но если я убираю, то они одновременно возьмут пару свободных вилок и я так понимаю происходит deadlock...Помогите пожалуйста

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Six {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        var philosopher = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        Eating eating = new Eating();
        eating.addFork();
        philosopher.add(new Thread(new Philosopher(1,2,eating)));
        philosopher.add(new Thread(new Philosopher(2,3,eating)));
        philosopher.add(new Thread(new Philosopher(3,4,eating)));
        philosopher.add(new Thread(new Philosopher(4,5,eating)));
        philosopher.add(new Thread(new Philosopher(5,6,eating)));
        philosopher.add(new Thread(new Philosopher(6,7,eating)));
        philosopher.add(new Thread(new Philosopher(7,1,eating)));

        philosopher.forEach(Thread::start);
    }
}
class Eating{

    private final HashMap<Integer,Integer> fork = new HashMap<>(); //0 - её нет в наличии , 1 - есть в наличии
    ReentrantLock locker;
    Condition condition;

    Eating(){
        locker = new ReentrantLock();
        condition = locker.newCondition();
    }

    void addFork() {
        fork.put(1, 1);
        fork.put(2, 1);
        fork.put(3, 1);
        fork.put(4, 1);
        fork.put(5, 1);
        fork.put(6, 1);
        fork.put(7, 1);
    }
    void getFork(int left,int right){

    locker.lock();
        try {

            while (true) {
                if (fork.get(left) == 1 && fork.get(right) == 1) {
                    fork.put(left, 0);
                    fork.put(right, 0);
                    System.out.println("Philosopher give " + left + " and " + right + " forks || Status table: "+fork);
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                    fork.put(left, 1);
                    fork.put(right, 1);
                    System.out.println("Philosopher was eating         || Status table: "+fork);
                    condition.signalAll();

                }

                condition.await();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        finally {
            locker.unlock();
        }


    }
}

class Philosopher implements Runnable{
    Eating eating;
    int right,left;
    public Philosopher(int left,int right,Eating eating){
        this.left=left;
        this.right=right;
        this.eating=eating;
    }
 @Override
 public void run(){
     try {
         Thread.sleep(300);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     eating.getFork(left,right);
 }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У тебя глобальный лок на весь метод, естественно, они его только по очереди могут получить и только по-очереди берут вилки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В твоём коде всё примерно происходит так

1. Получить лок
2. Получить вилки (лок всё ещё удерживается)
3. Подержать вилки 4 секунды (лок всё ещё удерживается, поэтому никто не может другие вилки взять)
4. Разослать уведомление, отпустить лок

Поэтому пока кто-то один держит вилки, он заодно держит и лок. Тебе надо на время удержания вилок отпускать лок, чтобы кто-то мог взять другие вилки.

```
while (true) {
 lock.lock();
 if (fork.get(left) == 1 && fork.get(right) == 1) {
   fork.put(left, 0);
   fork.put(right, 0);
   lock.unlock();  
   Thread.sleep(4000);

   lock.lock();
   fork.put(left, 1);
   fork.put(right, 1);
   condition.signalAll();
   lock.unlock();  
 } else {
   lock.unlock();  
 }
}
```

---

Тут, кстати, можно без глобальных `lock` и `condition` сделать, если использовать `AtomicBoolean`

```
private final HashMap<Integer,AtomicBoolean> fork = new HashMap<>(); //true - её нет в наличии , false - есть в наличии
...
fork.put(1, new AtomicBoolean());
...

while (true) {
 int first = left <= right ? left : right;
 int second = left <= right ? right : left;  
 if (fork.get(first).compareAndSet(false, true)) {
   if (fork.get(second).compareAndSet(false, true)) { 
     System.out("eating");
     Thread.sleep(4000);
     fork.get(second).set(false);
   }
   fork.get(first).set(false);
 }
 Thread.yield();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает, свою ошибку понял